# The custom ActiveRecord class not working when i call the find() method from view?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I am overriding the find method and add the where condition globally thats working fine here is my code

```
class Order extends \common\components\ActiveRecord
```

**`\common\components\ActiveRecord`**

```
namespace common\components;
use Yii;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord as BaseActiveRecord;

class ActiveRecord extends BaseActiveRecord{
    public static function find() {
        return parent::find()
           ->where(['=',static::tableName().'.company_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id])
           ->andWhere(['=',static::tableName().'.branch_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->branch_id]);
    }
}
```

The find is not working when i call the model from view like this

```
 echo  \common\models\Order::find()->where(['status'=>'0'])->count();
```

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam

Comment: Sir please have a look it is confusing me

Comment: Because you're overriting `where()` conditions, in your query change `where(['status' => '0'])` to `->andWhere(['status' => 0])`

Comment: @Yupik oo yes so its mean i need to replace the where from all the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `where()` inside the find function that you're using in `ActiveRecord` and then where() in this statement

```
echo  \common\models\Order::find()->where(['status'=>'0'])->count();
```

the second ends up overriding the first

What you need to do is to use andWhere() in all the cases where you need the original conditions that you put in ActiveRecord to work. Try thus:

```
echo  \common\models\Order::find()->andWhere(['status'=>'0'])->count();
```

This should work.

**And again remember, use andWhere() in all places where the original condition needs to be applied**

Answer (score 1):

Use `andWhere()` so your default condition not get overridden :

```
class ActiveRecord extends BaseActiveRecord {
    public static function find() {
        return parent::find()
            ->andWhere(['=',static::tableName().'.company_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id])
            ->andWhere(['=',static::tableName().'.branch_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->branch_id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is no where conditon what happen with the query..?

Comment: Nothing. Still these condition get applied.

Comment: @Insame Skull !

Comment: @Sajid https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/QueryTrait.php#L101

Comment: if where is false in any query then ..?

Comment: @Insame Skull not working i need to replace the where to and where in find()->andWhere

Comment: @Sajid `andWhere()` automatically converted to where, if there is no where condition.

Comment: Hello the where condition in my local condition overide this globla condition when i use the find()->where(['id'=>87]) in local mode the above condition ger ignored

Comment: @Sajid  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/QueryTrait.php#L101 according to this it's not possible it will not override where.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change with onCondition()

```
class ActiveRecord extends BaseActiveRecord {
   public static function find() {
     return parent::find()
        ->onCondition([
        ['=',static::tableName().'.company_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id],
        ['=',static::tableName().'.branch_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->branch_id]
     ]);
   }
}
```